# Evaluate $\int_{0}^t \,dr \int_{0}^s \frac{min(r,u)}{ru} \,du$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I quite don’t get the following passage:
$$\int_{0}^t \,dr \int_{0}^s \frac{\min(r,u)}{ru} \,du = \int_{s}^t dr \int_{0}^s \frac1r \,du + \int_{0}^s dr \int_{0}^r \frac1r \,du + \int_{0}^s dr \int_{r}^s \frac1u \,du$$

I've calculated $$\int_{0}^t dr \int_{0}^s \frac{\min(r,u)}{ru} \,du = \int_{0}^t dr  \left[\int_{0}^r \frac1r \,du + \int_{r}^s \frac1u \,du \right] = \int_{0}^t (1+ln(s)-ln(r)) \,dr = \dots$$ but it doesn't look I'm right.

Any help?

Answer (score 2):

The quoted formula is valid under assumption $s\le t$. It helps to draw the rectangle $[0,s]\times [0,t]$ and the line $u=r$ crossing it. Then you'll see three regions that are easy to integrate over: rectangle $[0,s]\times [s,t]$ and two symmetric halves of the square $[0,s]\times [0,s]$. Rectangle gives
$$
 \int_{s}^t dr \int_{0}^s \frac1r \,du $$
and the two halves of the square, separated by $u=r$, contribute 
$$\int_{0}^s dr \int_{0}^r \frac1r \,du + \int_{0}^s dr \int_{r}^s \frac1u \,du$$